# QGIS WMS/WMST referer

Tags: qgis, wms

In QGIS WMS/WMST connection we can define a *Referer (URL)* as can be seen here:

[image]

Since I was not able to find an exact definition for this:

Q: What is a referer and what is it used for?

Comment: more details at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a normal web page request the referer header is used to tell the server where the page request came from. Normally, it is optional and so QGis doesn't need to worry about it.

Some sites will "require" you to be using their map viewer (out of a misguided sense of needing security or something) and so will not return tiles unless the request has "come" from that page. This setting allows you to tell the server that you have been sent from a particular page.

If you don't need to set this specifically to make a server work then you can safely ignore it.